# How to say "I want to let my hair grow"

Tags: expressions

I have tried "j'essaie à laisser grandir mes cheveux" but that does not sound right, would “pousser” work?

Answer (score 7):

Je veux me laisser pousser les cheveux.

Answer (score 1):

"*Je veux laisser mes cheveux pousser*" would also work, and has exactly the same structure as the English sentence.